# Proving a statement in quadratic variation that ${\langle X \rangle}^{\tau} = \langle X^{\tau} \rangle$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, quadratic-variation

Let $\tau$ be a stopping time and $X$ be a continuous local martingale. Let $\langle \cdot \rangle$ denote the quadratic variation. We want to show that  $${\langle X \rangle}^{\tau} =  \langle X^{\tau} \rangle.$$

Does anyone know how to justify this statement, as it is not obvious at all from the definition of quadratic variation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a continuous martingale. We know that the compensator $(\langle X \rangle_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is the **unique** increasing predictable process such that

$$X_t^2 - \langle X \rangle_t$$

is a martingale. It follows from the optional stopping theorem that

$$X_{t \wedge \tau}^2 - \langle X \rangle_{t \wedge \tau} = (X^{\tau}_t)^2 - \langle X \rangle^{\tau}_t$$

is a martingale. As the compensator is unique, we conclude

$$\langle X \rangle^{\tau}_t = \langle X^{\tau} \rangle_t$$

for all $t \geq 0$.

Comment: But $X$ is assumed to be a continuous local martingale, which is more general than a martingale. In fact, the theorem on my book says that $X^2 - \langle X \rangle $ is a martingale if X is a continuous martingale such that $\sup_{t \geq 0} \mathbb{E} [X^2_t] < +\infty$.

Comment: @erik Yeah, so take a localizing sequence of stopping times and apply this to the stopped process.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand where does the square in the term $(X^{\tau}_t)^2$ go? Also, I don't understand how the uniqueness of the compensator was used.

Comment: @erik What do you mean by "where does there square [...] go"? The square is still there, isn't it? Obviously, $X_{t \wedge \tau}^2 = (X_t^{\tau})^2$. Concerning uniqueness: If $(Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a cts. martingale, then $A_t$ (increasing, predictable) equals $\langle Y \rangle_t$ if and only if $$Y_t^2 - A_t$$ is a martingale. Apply this for $Y_t := X_{t}^{\tau}$, $A_t := \langle X \rangle_t^{\tau}$.

Comment: Thanks for quoting this result. I haven't learnt this theorem before. Anyway, I meant that the square disappeared in the third line in my comment above.